# Solving the Differential equation $y' = y \tan(x) + \cot(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to solve the following differential equation:

$$y' = y \tan(x) + \cot(x)$$

What I have so far is

$$
\begin{align*}
y' - (\tan x) y &= \cot(x)\\
\\
I &= e^{\int - \tan(x) dx} = \cos(x)\\
\\
\cos(x) \left( y' - y \tan(x) \right) &= \cos(x) \cot(x)\\
y' \cos(x) - y \sin(x) &= \cos(x) \cot(x)\\
\int y' \cos(x) - y \sin(x) &= \int \cos(x) \cot(x) dx\\
\\
y \cos(x) &= \int \frac{cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)}\\
y \cos(x) &= \int \frac{1-sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)}\\
&= \int \csc(x) - \sin(x) \ dx\\
&= - \ln \vert \csc(x) + \cot(x) \vert + \cos(x) + C\\
\\
\therefore y &= - \frac{\ln \vert \csc(x) + \cot(x) \vert}{\cos(x)} + 1 + C \sec(x)
\end{align*}
$$

The thing is: I am having a hard time comparing my result to the textbook's solution and to [Wolfram's solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%20%3D%20y*%20tan(x)%20%2B%20cot(x)).

**Textbook's solution:** $$\sec(x) \left( \frac{x}{2} + \frac{\sin(2x)}{4} + C \right)$$

Is my solution correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is correct and is equivalent to WA's. The textbook answer is wrong

Comment: Hi @DavidQuinn thank you for your input. How could I go from my answer to Wolfram's (or the opposite)? What kind of transformation did you do?

Comment: Use $\csc x+\cot x=\cot(\frac x2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain the textbook's answer, note that in that case one would have

\begin{align}
y'(x)-y \tan x
&=\sec x \tan x  \left( \frac{x}{2} + \frac{\sin 2x }{4} + C \right)+\sec x  \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\cos 2x }{2} \right)
\\&\hspace{4mm} -\sec x\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sin 2x }{4} + C \right)\tan x \\
&= \frac{1 + \cos 2x }{2\cos x}\\&=\cos x
\end{align}
i.e. the textbook's answer is for the RHS being $\cos x$ rather than $\cot x$.

Comment: awesome, thank you! Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln \vert \csc(x) + \cot(x) \vert=\ln{|\frac{1+\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}|}=\ln{|\frac{2\cos^2{(x/2)}}{2\sin{(x/2)\cos(x/2)}}|}=\ln{\cos{(x/2)}}-\ln{\sin(x/2)}$, your solution is same as WolphramAlpha's.